# Abstracted model interface in Play! ORM, how does initial-data.yml get loaded?

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm, persistence, playframework

I have a model called Booking which has a persistent DateTime field. However I do not want to interact directly with this field, but rather through two Transient String fields, *date* and *time*. The problem is that I have no idea how/when play loads the data into the fields - it doesn't seem to be using the constructor I provide because the DateTime field is always null.

```
public class Booking extends Model {

  @Column
  @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
  public DateTime datetime;
  public Integer duration;
  @Transient
  public String date = "1970-01-01";
  @Transient
  public String time = "00:00";

  public Booking(String date, String time, Integer duration) {
    this.datetime = toDateTime(date, time);
    this.duration = duration;
  }

  public void setDate(String dateStr) {
    this.date = dateStr;
    this.datetime = toDateTime(dateStr, this.time);
  }

  public void setTime(String timeStr) {
    this.time = timeStr;
    this.datetime = toDateTime(this.date, timeStr);
  }

  public String getDate() {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return this.datetime.toString(format); //NullPointerException here!
  }

  public String getTime() {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("kk:mm");
    return this.datetime.toString(format);//NullPointerException here!
  }
```

here's the toDateTime method:

```
  private DateTime toDateTime(String date, String time){
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute();
    DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(date+"T"+time);

    return dt;
  }
```

Comment: I just need to know what order JPA would load the entities to make sure the other field it depends on is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you can define a default constructor that takes no parameters to set up your object when JPA loads it. Like so:

```
public Booking() {
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinute();
  this.datetime = fmt.parseDateTime("1970-01-01T00:00");
}
```

Now the only problem is that it uses the same setters I've defined when retrieving from the database: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "ISO8601:2011-08-25T02:00:00+0200..."
**

Answer (score 2):

JPA, which play uses, uses a default empty constructor to initiate the class. In your case the Play framework (I guess) creates a Booking() constructor. JPA then uses the getters and setters to set the properties of your entity.

Perhaps you could use the  @PostLoad annotation from JPA. Which causes the annotated method to be called after your persistent data is loaded into the Entity.

**Update:** I mentioned @PostLoad, but perhaps the @PrePersist is an better option, to check if you DateTime field is null and if this is the case you could set it with your default value. Thus like so:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist()
{
    if(this.dateTime==null)
    {
        this.dateTime = toDateTime(this.date, this.time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. `@PostLoad` works but `@PrePersist` doesn't. Also, I had to specify the default values in the method call as such: 
`this.datetime = toDateTime("1970-01-01", "00:00");`

Comment: Hang on, now there's the issue that the values are forever bound to its default value instead of being set by the getters and setters of the `time` and `date` fields.

Comment: I do not understand why your field is null. If you create a new Booking with your constructor, the datetime member variable can never be null. Persisting the object then should result in a value stored in the database. Please check your database if the value is actually stored. If this is not the case, there is something wrong with the Joda DateTime i guess. 
I don't know the Joda DateTime.

Comment: The data is loaded by play Bootstrap, using `Fixtures.loadModels("initial-data.yml");`. Using the debugger, neither my constructor, nor the setters are being called. I'll implement a test to see if this behaviour is isolated to the bootstrap only.

Comment: The Fixtures uses default constructors as well, and perhaps it does not call the and setXXX methods directly. Thus I guess the @PrePersist should work to ensure your dateTime field is set correclty. Can you supply an example of the .yml file where you create a Booking?

Comment: here's the yaml: [link](http://pastebin.com/rzvCP1xY).
here's the complete class: [link](http://pastebin.com/LWQGbnqr)

Answer (score 0):

I presume DateTime is joda DateTime in the above code. I don't think JPA/Hibernate supports this data type for persistence. The ones supported are Timestamp, Calendar available as part of JDK.

You have to define a new user type in Hibernate to work with DateTime. Check this [link](http://objectopia.com/2009/07/10/joda-with-jpa/)

Comment: [Another example](http://nerdgerl.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/how-to-map-joda-times-with-hibernate/)

Comment: I'm using joda-time-hibernate, which does support it. I just omitted the annotations in my code example.[link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html)